# Blinking of UIViewController while navigation from UICollectionViewController to UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am Navigating from `UICollectionViewController` to `UIViewController` by using `UINavigationController`. When my `UIViewController` load it blink half screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should  use interface builder and use segue for navigation.
its working with me. try it...